# Cannot open System Settings on Linux mint 20.1

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I can't open my System Settings and when I try to start it from terminal with command `cinnamon-settings` I got this error :

```
Using PAM module (python3-pam)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 731, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 310, in __init__
    for module in modules:
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_user.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_share_cinnamon_cinnamon-settings_cinnamon-settings.py.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 731, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 310, in __init__
    for module in modules:
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_user.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help fix this please ?

Comment: Did you update anything recently? What about **python**?

Comment: I'm not really sure it's been long time I have this problem but now I need to fix it and I can't figure out how

Answer (score 0):

You have a GUI.
Sign-in as a user into Mint, using the Cinnamon DE.

Either open system-settings from the menu, or

Run the `cinnamon-settings` command from a gnome-terminal (known as "terminal").

**cinnamon-settings runs the graphical user interface allowing to configure Cinnamon.** [from the man cinnamon-settings page].

Comment: This what I did, I'm already using the GUI

Comment: Oops! - Just tried my VM of Mint 20.2 and it seized up; very strange.